# Socket.io-redis gives error when added as adapter to Socket.io instance

Tags: node.js, redis, windows-10, node-cluster, socket.io-redis

Im experimenting abit with Socket.io and Socket.Io-redis. 
I have my Redis server up and running. 
The error i get when starting the Socket.Io server is: 
ReplyError: ERR unknown command 'pubsub'
I dont know why i get this error at all.

The Redis version i'm using is 2.4.5

```
io.adapter(redisIO({host: 'localhost', port: 6379}));
```

```
io.of('/').adapter.clients((err, clients) => {
            if(err){
                console.log('error!!')
                throw err;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing latest version of Redis! :)